# Setting the subclass of a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, subclass

I have created a project where I have a UITableViewController with static cells. I have created a UITableViewController subclass so that I can write the code for some of the controls I want to put in the static cells - however when I set the custom class of the UITableViewController to that of the subclass I've created, the table isn't displayed. Coudl anyone please help me with what to do that the table will be displayed after I've set the custom class of the UITableViewController?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you set the delegate and the datasource of the table to your custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using storyboard and static cells: make sure the `datasource` methods in your controller do are not overriding the number of sections and rows in the table view. With static cells you can delete both `numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSections`.